# Android support library 23.2.0 preview error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-support-library, android-design-library

I have just update my support libraries to 23.2.0 and get error: I can't see any view from Android Design Support Library (such as `FloatingActionButton`) in Android Studio  preview.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAppPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Subtitle"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/recyclerview_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:contentPadding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_user_fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

And stack:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10e0000 type #0x0 is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1110)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonEclairMr1.<init>(FloatingActionButtonEclairMr1.java:46)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonIcs.<init>(FloatingActionButtonIcs.java:31)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.<init>(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:44)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.createImpl(FloatingActionButton.java:648)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.getImpl(FloatingActionButton.java:640)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(FloatingActionButton.java:192)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompatLollipop.java:82)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompat.java:1623)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompat.java:2925)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:62)
    at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:37)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:109)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1669.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:169)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:359)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: the preview is not very reliable so I wouldnt worry about it. Just run the app and see what it looks like on your device/emulator

Comment: @tyczj, yes, on my device/emulator all works fine, but in Support Library 22.1 preview was available and I saw `FloatingActionButton` background.

Comment: so its a bug with the support library, many people have had similar problems. All that matters is what it looks like on the device so use that

Comment: @tyczj, So many bugs...and one more problem: I'm tried of this warnings. Can I disable it?

Comment: there is an `x` there, click it

Comment: @tyczj, I mean prevent its appearance.

Comment: I dont know that you can, I dont bother with the designer view so cant answer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a drawable mutation bug as being worked on Google with the 23.2.0 release. [See the issue here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817). Reverting back to 23.1.1 should be fine until the next bugfix release.

Comment: Thank you for information. Unfortunately, I can't revert back, because of using new  `BottomSheetDialog`.